# why i get this error jq: error Cannot index array with string from json file?

Tags: bash, shell, jq

i'm trying to build script that takes specific attribute value and store it in the array , this is the following JSON file:

```
    [
 {
  "id": 1, 
  "name": "myna", 
  "description": "Simple Question", 
  "speaker": "USER", 
 }, 
 {
  "all_Id's": [
   "11111"
  ], 
  "user": "me", 
 }, 
 {
  "id": 2, 
  "name": "mry", 
  "description": "Simple", 
  "speaker": "aaa",
 }
  ]
```

as you see object in json file don't have the same attributes so i'm looking only on object has "name " attribute,the following script  reads the Json file and return the values of **attribute name only** ,but i build something wrond as theERROR always on the "{" of the last object in file I don't know why , what i am i doing wrong?
the expected output is : [myna, mry]

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a OB_I=()
declare counter1=0
jq -r '.name' file.json ; while read -r val ; do
  if [[ ! $val ]]
    then
     OB_I[$counter]=$val ;
     counter=$((counter+1));
    fi
  done;
$ printf '%s\n' "${OB_I[@]}"
```

Comment: If the `while` loop is supposed to consume the output of `jq`, you want a pipe (`|`), not a semicolon (`;`) before the `while` keyword.

Comment: The putative "JSON file" does not contain valid JSON.  You could either fix it manually, or use a converter such as hjson to rectify it.

Answer (score 0):

The input of `jq` is a list, which doesn't have *any* keys, let alone one named `name`. You want

```
jq -r '.[].name'
```

instead.

Unrelated, you don't need the variable `counter`. You can simply append to your array with `OB_I+=("$val")`.

Comment: hi , thank you for the first part of the solution , as for the second part ,i've used this method before and simply it doesn't add the value at all to the array i don't know why